# Internship to full time - how to handle telling my boss

Tags: professionalism, internship

I applied for a job after I was laid off from my old position as a system admin. I was not offered a full-time job, but I was offered an internship with the caveat that I would go back to school and complete my B.S. degree in the fall.

I only have a two year degree right now and I never really wanted to get my B.S, but knew I really wanted to work full-time again so I took the internship while looking for another job. I've finally gotten a full-time offer that does not require me to go back to school.

How do I handle telling my boss I'm leaving the intern position while still being professional?

Comment: So, you were at company A, got laid off, have been working as an intern at company A, and just got a job offer from company B?  Isn't giving 2 weeks notice and going to the new company all you need to do to be professional?

Comment: No Company A laid me off, Company B gave me an internship, and now company C has offered me a full time position

Comment: Ah, and the internship at company B is based on you becoming a student, but you aren't going to do that now.

Comment: Correct. I have my associates and in my field that really is all you need.

Answer (score 6):

This one's easy.

> Hello boss, my plans have changed.  Here's my 2-week notice.

Life happens.  You don't owe your boss any explanation at all, so a simple "my plans have changed" should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

As a professional, your boss won't take it personally.  Just give your standard 2-week notice.

If you fail to do that (for example, suddenly not show up to work or give less than 2 weeks notice) then it could affect your professional references later on... references and experience are crucial to your career, so don't do anything to jeopardize any of them if possible.